# How to scrape simple image from webpage

Tags: python-3.x

I am very very new to python.
when I run the below:

```
from PIL import Image

import requests

import bs4


url = 'https://parts.bmwmonterey.com/a/BMW_2004_330i-Sedan/_52014_5798240/Cooling-System-Water-Hoses/17_0215.html'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

image = soup.find('img')
image_url = image['src']


img = Image.open(requests.get(image_url, stream = True).raw)

img.save('image.jpg')
```

I got this error:

> Invalid URL '/images/parts/BMW/fullsize/158518.jpg': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///images/parts/BMW/fullsize/158518.jpg?

Comment: There are a few ways. One is to use selenium to simulate manual download. One more is to extract the image urls, research how to download image from url with python.

Comment: Try to code something and then show us your work if it gives an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the image_url gives the directory of the image where it stored on the hosting service. You need to append the domain name to the image_url variable and use the requests library to download it.

Use the following code and it will work.

```
import bs4
import requests

url = "https://parts.bmwmonterey.com/a/BMW_2004_330i-Sedan/_52014_5798240/Cooling-System-Water-Hoses/17_0215.html"

resp = requests.get(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")

img = soup.find('img')

image = img["src"]

img_url = "https://parts.bmwmonterey.com" + str(image)

r = requests.get(img_url)

with open("image.jpg","wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: glad you found the error. consider accepting this as a valid answer by hitting the tick mark.